# Get generic of generic in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a class. It will be simple container, which may contain some type `T` and type `Optional<T>` (guava `Optional` [link](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html))
With `Container.of(T)` there is no problems. But, how can create `Container.ofOptional(T)`?
Here is my class:

```
public final class Container<T>{
  Class<?> firstClass;
  Class<T> seconClass;

  Container(Class<?> first, Class<T> second){
    this.firstClass = first;
    this.seconClass = second;
  }

  public static <T> Container<T> of(Class<?> first, Class<T> second){
    return new Container(first, second);
  }

  public static <T> Container<Optional<T>> ofOptional(Class<?> first, Class<T> second){
    return of(first, <what should I pass here>);
  }
}
```

I tried `Optional.of(second)` but it doesn't work.

So, in result, I want method `Container.ofOptional(T)` return `Container<Optional<T>>`

Comment: `Optional.of(second)` isn't viable since you claim to be returning a `Container<Optional<T>>`, and at best with that, you're returning an `Optional<Class<T>>`.  I've been looking at this for a while now and I'm quite perplexed about its use case.  Why are you just passing classes around instead of anything more concrete?

Comment: If you put `return new Container(first, second);` to `ofOptional`, Java compiles correctly. But, what is your purpose? What you need to do with `ofOptional`?

Comment: @Valijon, may be java compiles it correctly, but Intellij show me error about second argument `Required Optional<T>, Found Optional`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), this doesn't really make sense. There's only one `Optional.class` — `Optional.of("foo").getClass()` and `Optional.of(3).getClass()` both return the same instance — so although you can obtain an expression of type `Class<Optional<T>>` by lots of casting, its runtime-type will necessarily be `Class<Optional>` (or just null), so you can't do anything really useful with it.

So the simple answer to your question is that you can write

```
  public static <T> Container<Optional<T>> ofOptional(Class<?> first, Class<T> second){
    return of(first, (Class<Optional<T>>) (Class) Optional.class);
  }
```

but the real answer is that you shouldn't do this.

(You might want to post a new question about your *real* problem — the problem that `Container` is trying to solve — and perhaps someone can help you find a better approach.)

Comment: Thanks you very much. I don't reed to post new question, because your answer solved my problem.